# Hide outline focus on link when click

Tags: css, hyperlink, focus, tabindex, outline

I need to hide the focus outline when I click on a link.
But i also need to show it when I slide links with tabindex.
Some websites doing this with any specific workaround.It seems that is the dafault behaviour.
But in my website, when I click on a link it shows also the outline.
How can I show he outline only when I slide links with tabindex key?
Thanks in advance.
Helmut

Comment: what do you currently have ? Removing the outline is a simple CSS manipulation, having it at some point might be a bit trickier but doesn't look impossible. Have you read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/) yet ?

Comment: Yes, I know that i can remove the outline with a css properties, but I need to SHOW it when i press the tabindex key, as also the google homepage does.

Answer (score 1):

If the tab behaviour is specifically what you need to detect when adjusting the CSS outline property, I don't believe CSS can ascertain the input device type from the such states as :focus or :active.

Instead, you could hide the outline for all elements on the page with CSS:

```
a:focus, a:active {
  outline:0;
}
a.tabbed {
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

Then you'd to use JavaScript to adjust the outline for certain elements that receive focus with the tab key.

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var el = document.activeElement;

    if (code == 9 && el.tagName == 'A') {
        el.className = "tabbed";
    }
}, true);
```

I've added a quick example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aljsu